# Create EC2 in default public subnet only using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, subnet

I have CF template which is creating EC2 machine.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Mappings:
  InstanceAMI:
  # ubuntu 18.04
    us-west-2:
      ami: 'ami-0bbe6b35405ecebdb'
    us-east-1:
      ami: 'ami-0ac019f4fcb7cb7e6'

Parameters:
  Endpoint:
    Type: String
    # TODO edit the default value
    Description:

Resources:
  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - !Ref NodeInstanceRole

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess

  CdpDeplSvcSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Access Deployment service
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 8080
        ToPort: 8080
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: 'Access Deployment'

  DeploymentMachine:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      # AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: !FindInMap [InstanceAMI, !Ref "AWS::Region", ami]
      InstanceType: 't2.small'
      KeyName: 'key'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'Deployment'
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: "/dev/sda1"
          Ebs:
            # VolumeType: "io1"
            # Iops: "200"
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "30"
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: 0
          AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          GroupSet:
            - !GetAtt CdpDeplSvcSecurityGroup.GroupId
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
```

It executing correctly. But the problem I am facing is sometimes it creates in default private subnet, sometimes in default public subnet.
I want to deploy this machine in the **default public subnet** only. I don't want to pass VPC id or subnet id as parameter. For that, what I have change here.

Comment: Are you willing to hardcode the subnet ID? You have to provide it somehow, there's no magic here.

Comment: You must provide some indication of your desire by providing a subnet reference or even an Availability Zone (if each of the subnets is in a different AZ). Otherwise, it will be a random assignment. _Why_ do you not wish to pass a Subnet ID as a parameter?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein and guest There is a use case where I will not ask customer 's AWS details.(vpc id, subnet id). It should automatically take public subnet during EC2 creation. Before It was working fine, Suddenly it is started taking private subnet. So, Is it possible that it will take automatically public subnet?

Comment: Yes, you haven't specified anything (VPC, Subnet), so it will probably go into a random subnet within the Default VPC. One option would be to add a `Parameter` asking the user to provide a subnet. That way, you don't need to hard-code it into the template, but the instance can be specifically launched in the subnet that the user nominates when creating the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just put it into a random subnet - you need to hardcode subnet, or specify subnet through a parameter and then reference the parameter - this can provide you with some flexibility for varying the subnet per customer.

Potentially, during deployment of your stack, you could script the deployment, using the AWS CLI to get all public subnets, and pass one in as a parameter into your cloudformation stack.